# Underscore.js: TypeError: rc is undefined when using templates

Tags: javascript, jquery, underscore.js-templating

I'm using underscore.js to create templates. I am utilizing the `rc` variable discussed [here](https://github.com/jashkenas/underscore/issues/237#issuecomment-68874114) and I'm getting rc is undefined messages in my firebug console along with this tidbit:

```
((__t=( rc.siteid ))==null?'':_.escape(__t))+
```

I tried sending in empty json as specified like so: `var mytemplate = _.template([code], {})` as the issue comment suggested, but the error still persists and my templates don't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for me was to always explicitly send in an empty json `{}` if I didn't have any options to send in. The code would look like this:

```
var mytemplate = _.template([code]);
$('body').append(mytemplate({}));
```

I'm creating this question/answer because I did not find a solution on SO or via google.